# I'm not understanding what the error comment is trying to tell me

Tags: java, class, object, extends

I have a class named Circle and another class named POINT,thus Circle is made of radius and point(which is the center point of the circle).I'm trying to build a constructor and I bumped into an error message and I can't figure out the issue.

(Class Circle,the beginning of it)

```
public class Circle extends Shape {
    private int radius, x, y;

    Point point = new Point(0,0);

    public Circle(radius,x, y){
        this(5, 3, 6);
    }
```

Class Point:

```
    public class Point {
    private int xPos,yPos;
    public Point(int x, int y){
        setxPos(x);
        setyPos(y);
    }
    public int getxPos() {
        return xPos;
    }
    public void setxPos(int xPos) {
        this.xPos = xPos;
    }
    public int getyPos() {
        return yPos;
    }
    public void setyPos(int yPos) {
        this.yPos = yPos;
    }
    ...
```

Comment: What error message exactly?

Comment: And the error message is ... ?

Comment: Yes, interesting: this message is really very clear.

Comment: -syntax error on token ",", delete this token

Comment: Elementary fix: `public Circle(int radius, int x, int y)`

Comment: Sytax errors: You tackle them one by one, from  top to bottom

Comment: Tali, just copy and paste the error =) and edit your question, please

Comment: Do you have any other constructor in class **Circle** ? If not, then you cannot from within the constructor call itself by *this(a,b,c,)*
On a more basic level, your constructor does not define the type of its parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
     public Circle(radius,x, y){
       this(5, 3, 6);
   }
```

To

```
  public Circle(int radius,int x, int y){  //need to add types to parameters
              this.radius=radius;
              this.x=x;
              this.y=y;
   }
```

Or if you plan to use 5,3,6 as constant values add

```
  public Circle(){ 
              this.radius=5;
              this.x=3;
              this.y=6;
   }
```

Comment: now it says recursive constructor invocation (int,int,int)

Answer (score 1):

Your constructor is `recursive` eventhough your declaration is wrong as suggested by other answers I suggest you to change declaration and think again about your code you may want to initialize `radius,x and y` in constructor and you may want to declare some method to do operation on initialized value.

```
 public Circle(int radius,int x, int y){
  //Remove this from the constructor and perform initialization
  this.radius=radius;
  this.x=x;
  this.y=y
 }
```